# CSS/JS not linking to HTML page

Tags: javascript, css, npm, bootstrap-4, sass

I have created setup using below tutorial:
https://coursetro.com/posts/design/72/Installing-Bootstrap-4-Tutorial

When I run gulp file CSS/JS are not linked, I have applied bg color on body but not applying on this.

I have installed bootstrap 4 using npm and add gulpfile to process, below code is for gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
.pipe(sass())
.pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Move the javascript files into our /src/js folder
gulp.task('js', function() {
return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js'])
.pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"))
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('sass', function() {

browserSync.init({
server: "./src"
});

gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], gulp.series('sass'));
gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
}));

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], gulp.series('sass'));
});

gulp.task("default", gulp.series(gulp.parallel("js", "serve", 'sass')));
```

Using above code, localhost index page opened but css/js not applying on page:

CSS code:
body {background-color: #70501f; }

Showing error on console like:

> Refused to apply style from
> 'http://localhost:3000/src/css/bootstrap.css' because its MIME type
> ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
> checking is enabled. (index):1
> Refused to apply style from
> 'http://localhost:3000/src/css/style.css' because its MIME type
> ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
> checking is enabled.

CSS:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="/src/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="/src/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/src/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/src/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/src/js/popper.min.js"></script>
```

I have uploaded my code at here, please help me:
https://github.com/pradeepmpatel/bootstrap4tuts

Thanks
PP

Comment: What exacly is the question? Please add the code of what you created/tried

Comment: Thanks Ramon, I have updated my comments with more details.

Comment: I think your problem is not on the gulp file... how are you loading this styles on your html page?

Comment: I have added css at head section like this way:
 <link type="text/css" href="/src/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="/src/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: and added js as like this way:
<script type="text/javascript" src="/src/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/src/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/src/js/popper.min.js"></script>

Comment: When I see source code and click on css/js link, it is opened but it is not applying on page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the MIME Type error could be due to the css path not being correct. It's trying to serve up an error instead of the css file which is not matching the MIME type.
recheck your CSS & JS paths, it could be ./src or ./node_modules.

Comment: I have tried by adding path like you have suggested, but still not working :(

Comment: Do I also need to change path in gulp file?

Comment: I have uploaded my code at here, please help me:
https://github.com/pradeepmpatel/bootstrap4tuts

Comment: can you please check this? https://github.com/pradeepmpatel/bootstrap4tuts